# Change font size of TextView on AppWidget

Tags: java, android, widget, android-appwidget

From my configure activity the user can select his/hers desired font size of the widget. I set the font size like this:

```
RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget);
views.setFloat(R.id.tvConfigInput, "setTextSize", 25);
```

But I do not how to update the Widget with the selected size

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use your AppWidgetManager.For example in onReceive() method of your AppWidgetProvider do some things like this:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
                    R.layout.widget);
    AppWidgetManager mManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
    ComponentName cn = new ComponentName(context,YourAppWidgetProvider.class);
    ...
    mManager.updateAppWidget(cn, views);

}
```

Here `YourAppWidgetProvider` is name of class that extends `AppWidgetProvider`.

Answer (score 0):

What you have should work, as `setTextSize()` is a `RemotableViewMethod` (at least in the current source code) and therefore should work with `RemoteViews`.

First, try your app widget on an Android 4.2 emulator and see if it works. If it does, then the answer is that `setTextSize()` is usable on Android 4.2, is not usable on whatever environment you originally tried, and should become usable somewhere in between them.

Otherwise, make sure that you are actually updating the app widget, using `AppWidgetManager` and methods like `updateAppWidget()`.